# What's the best way to write a "has_many :through" so that it just uses a plain WHERE query, instead of an INNER JOIN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have a User model. All users belongs to a company, and companies have many Records:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :records
end

class Record < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I'm using Devise to authenticate users, so I want to start all my queries with `current_user`, to make sure I'm only returning records that the user is allowed to see. I just want to call something like:

```
current_user.company_records
```

(I don't want to call `current_user.company.records`, because I don't need to load the Company. I just need the records.)

If I do:

```
has_many :company_records, source: :records, through: :company
```

Then Rails does an inner join, which is gross:

```
2.3.3 :030 > user.company_records
  Record Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" INNER JOIN "companies" ON 
    "records"."company_id" = "companies"."id" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

I have to do this:

```
has_many :company_records,
          class_name: 'Record',
          primary_key: :company_id,
          foreign_key: :company_id
```

Then Rails will just run a simple "where" query (which has the proper indexes):

```
2.3.3 :039 > user.company_records
  Record Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", 1]]
```

Is there a nicer way of writing this? I could just do:

```
def company_records
  Record.where(company_id: company_id)
end
```

... but I want to know if there's a more idiomatic way to do it with ActiveRecord associations.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably use delegate ?

```
delegate :records, to: :company, prefix: true
```

Then you can directly use

```
current_user.company_records
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but `delegate` will also load the company before it loads any records. This is the unnecessary query that I am trying to avoid.